# Binding values to a multi dimensional object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object where I wish to store separate data in

```
users: [
    {
        'names': [],
        'addresses': [],
    }
],
```

I have checkboxes like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="john" value="john" v-model="users.names">
```

I want to bind the checkbox with the names array.

But it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Why do you want to bind an array to a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

you csn use v-for:

html:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="user in users">
        <input  id="john" value="john" v-model="user.names">
     </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data(){
    return {
      users: [
        {
           names: [],
           addresses: [],
        }
      ],
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `users` is an array; Maybe you want to do this?

```js
<input type="checkbox" id="john" value="john" v-model="users[0].names">
//                                                          ^^^  bind to the first element in the users
```

which [worked for me](https://jsfiddle.net/cwnaLy8n/1/).

Or define `users` as an object:

```
users: {
  'names': [],
  'addresses': [],
}
```